# Mouseover event is glitchy

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, mouseover, mouseout

I am pretty new to javascript so for lack of a better word I'm using the term "glitchy" to describe what is going on with the event. So when I hover the text "Show message", a text box is supposed to appear saying "Welcome to IT 202". While it is working, it seems very finnicky. When I hover over the text the banner flickers in and out, and it is also kinda picky as to where I am exactly hovering. So I just want to make it so when I hover the message displays and doesn't flicker, and when I mouse out it disappears.

```js
const text = document.getElementById("text");
const banner = document.getElementById("banner");

text.addEventListener("mouseover", over);
text.addEventListener("mouseout", out);

function over() {
  banner.style.display = "block";
}

function out() {
  banner.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
h1 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  color: white;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}


#text {
  color: blueviolet;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
}


p {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px'
}
```

```html
<h1 id="banner">Welcome to IT202</h1>
<p>
  <strong>Mouse over the text "Show Welcome" and the welcome message is displayed. Mouse out and the welcome messages disappears!</strong>
</p>
<p1 id="text">Show Welcome</p1>
```

I tried changing the padding and margins to see if maybe that was causing it but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I think your moveover handler is changing the position of your text element. Causing a mouseout event, and so on causing a flicker. Try wrapping your banner in a div with a fixed height.

Comment: No that isn't really working cause it's still doing the same thing.  I think the problem is the text that you hover over which triggers the banner to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the `<p1 id="text">Show Welcome</p1>` element is affected by the position of the `banner` element. When the `banner` disappears, it causes a change in the position of the `text`, similar to a mouse-out effect. I don't know if that is what you want exactly but you can alter the `visibility` instead of the `display`, so that the position of `text` won't change:

```js
const text = document.getElementById("text");
const banner = document.getElementById("banner");
text.addEventListener("mouseover", over);
text.addEventListener("mouseout", out);

function over() {
  banner.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function out() {
  banner.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
h1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  color: white;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#text {
  color: blueviolet;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px'

}
```

```html
<h1 id="banner">Welcome to IT202</h1>
<p><strong>Mouse over the text "Show Welcome" and the welcome message is displayed. Mouse out and the welcome messages disappears!</strong></p>
<p1 id="text">Show Welcome</p1>
```

I assume any solution that not allows the `text` to move as a consequence would work (placing the `banner` under the `text`, making the `text` position obsolete, etc.)